# How to validate a string in regex condition in required field validator in c#

Tags: regex

How to validate the below combination of inputs in input box in c#?

Volume/Issue ->  1/1  or 1/1S OR 1/1(S) or 1/S1

I have tried the below regex condition separately working fine and how to combine both regex pattern or both condition to match any pattern

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]+/[a-zA-Z0-9]+

[a-zA-Z0-9]+/[0-9]+\([a-zA-Z]+\)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `[0-9A-Za-z]+` as the second character class instead of matching only digits, and optionally match the parts between parenthesis.

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]+/[0-9A-Za-z]+(?:\([a-zA-Z]+\))?
```

- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+/[0-9A-Za-z]+` Match a part where `/` is between 1+ chars out of a-zA-Z0-9
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\([a-zA-Z]+\)` Match `(` 1+ chars a-zA-Z and `)`
- `)?` Close the group and make it optional

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/B8LYLV/1)

Comment: How about the string 1/S1

Comment: Can you explain this (?:\([a-zA-Z]+\))?

Comment: @HaridassTR I have added an explanation about the pattern. This part `(?:([a-zA-Z]+))?` makes the whole parts with the parenthesis optional.

Comment: ++ for good solution. Post was unfairly closed. Voted to reopen